# Android source code submit patch

Tags: android, repo

I want add a patch for android source code.
Have downloaded the code after the instruction from: 
https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

After that i follow the steps in:
http://source.android.com/source/submit-patches.html

When i should start a new repo branch:
repo start NAME .

I get error:
error: project . not found

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: You should've checkout from git instead of downloading the source code. Besides this is off-topic here

Comment: How do I do that? IS there any guide for doing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 2):

This error will occur if you try to run the command `repo start NAME .` inside the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` folder. This is because the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` folder is not a git repository. You need to go to some inner folder in which there is a git repository you need. Inside the folder, that is the git repository, or in one of its parent folders, there must be a `.git` folder. For example, go to this folder: `/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget`. Inside this folder, run the command `repo start NAME .`